# spam issues with sending millions of emails

Tags: email, smtp

I am currently developing an email server in C, and the end goal is to be able to send millions of emails to millions of people every day. Many organizations have email lists with large numbers of users that they email every week/month/etc.

The big question: **how can I prevent the server and the emails from being marked as a spam?**  All of the SPAM-prevention stuff I've seen so far deals mostly with poor configurations, or at least does not require large numbers of emails to be send every hour.  I have yet to see anything that addresses the scope of millions-of-emails-per-hour.

Here are some assumptions you can make:

- EVERY single email sent is legitimate
- all SPF records and MX records are accurate, up-to-date, and valid
- all other common SPAM-prevention tactics are being used (reverse DNS is good, DKIM is used, return-addresses are valid, etc etc etc)
- emails are one-to-one (ie, I'm not CC'ing 1000 gmail addresses; I'm sending one email to each address)

Here are some questions to get us moving in the right direction:

- should I limit the number of emails sent to X emails per minute per domain?  If so, how do sites like GMail and MailChimp get around this? *note: there are no ISP restrictions; this is only an issue for the receiving mail server...*
- should I limit the number of connections to a domain at a given time? (eg, will Google think I'm a spam agent if I open 10/100/1000 simultaneous connections to gmail servers?)
- how many bounce-backs (5xx errors on an address) should I accept for automatically removing that email from a subscription list? does this affect a server's spam rating?
- is there anything else I should or should not do?

Final note: please remember this is a *programming* question, NOT a library question - I don't want to use someone else's service; we are writing our own for a reason.  I'm looking for practical programming advice.

Comment: I've never dealt with millions of emails - the most in one "batch" to be sent was around 25,000. We were able to accomplish that while assuring the same things you have (your assumptions) and sending out what basically worked out to 1 per second on two separate servers.  So, technically 2 per second.  We did not have the need to push it any further than that.  We did not get blacklisted or have any issues with spam.  That's all I can add I'm afraid, but its something.

Comment: If you send an email to a person for the first time it is already possible that their provider will junk the mail. This is usual scenario with forum registration emails and similar, they end in junk even if they are legitimate and forum mail servers could be sending a lot per day.
If all receivers are familiar with the sending email it should be allright. And if they are not I question the source of your emails.

Comment: Also, if you have a large number of recepients in a single mail it is already a warning to spam filter. Since you will have a dedicated program to send them you can simply avoid this and send one by one directly to the user, no mass mailing. Google for "common spam filters"

Comment: Luke, thanks for the advice, but one of our clients has an email list with 63 million addresses on it.  If I wanted to deliver emails for just them within one hour, I would need 17,500 servers.  That's obviously not ideal :/

Comment: Cen, I like your idea of "building rapport" on the IP and domain name before attempting something large.  Thanks for the advice.

And I forgot to mention, but almost all emails are one-to-one. I'll update my post.

Comment: The companies I know that do this with significant email volume have employees that have full-time jobs negotiating with major email providers to avoid this.  This is not a strictly technology problem.

Comment: I use MailGun for my app to send large (although nowhere near as large as you're talking) volumes of mail. They use a ramping up algorithm to avoid getting black-flagged. http://documentation.mailgun.net/faqs.html#deliverability-reputation Their doco also has some good tips on the subject.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It should be on superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a programming question, but here goes:

I strongly recommend you join your local mail operators mailing list, as well as "Spam-L" mailing list. Read the archives, and see what issues others are having.

The short answer is that destination servers can, and do, use all sorts of methods to try to prevent spam. THere are many things you will need to be aware of in order to have good deliverability, and ***those things change all the time***.

- **First** and most important, remember:

  ***Free speech also includes free listening.*** 
  Nobody has to accept or transmit your mail.

  Independent operators, businesses and individuals have a perfect right to refuse your mail for any reason or no reason. ISPs are limited only by their contracts with the customer and common-carrier laws, which generally give them broad discretion in what is considered spam and how they block it.
- **Their system, their rules.** If you want your messages delivered, you must cooperate with receiving ISPs. This may mean jumping through hoops, or complying with requirements you think are stupid, or pointless.
- **Ensure you are not listed by SpamHaus.** Most ISPs small and large use SpamHaus DNSBL service. Presence on one of SpamHaus' lists asserts their opinion that your mail meets their listing criteria. Because of SpamHaus' high reputation, most ISPs will simply block all mail you send based on their opinion.
- **Make sure you process unsubscribes.**
- **Make sure you process non-delivery reports.** You may not want to kill a subscription on the first NDR, as there can be intermittent network or server problems which can result in non-delivery, or even erroneous reports that an address is incorrect. But if you get several over the course of a month or two with no successful deliveries, you should kill the subscription.
- **Join a pay-for reputation service.** These may require posting a bond which you may lose if you send Spam. SpamHaus offer one. There are others.
- **Get professional advice** from someone like Return-Path. You will have to pay for this also.
- **Monitor**. The hoops you have to jump through change all the time. Ensure you are aware of emerging deliverability problems.
- **Join feedback loops.** most large ISPs offer feedback programmes where you can get feedback on how users are perceiving your mail, whether they are reporting it as spam, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Ben had some good practical advice, but for others with this problem, here is what I have discovered in the past month:

**Email is all about *REPUTATION***.  You will never be able to throw together a server, ip, and/or domain name and expect to be able to send out millions upon millions of emails.

On Stack Overflow, we have a rating system (up and downvotes) to estimate the value/trust that person has with the SO community.  But it takes time and effort to get points.  It's the same with email - you have to start sending out small amounts of email that people actually open up and read (and would never mark as spam), and then slowly send out more and more every month until you reach the goal of millions and millions of emails.

Everytime someone "downvotes" - marks the email as spam, flags the domain, flags the ip address, deletes the email without reading it, etc - you get a hit against your reputation.  You need to be continually monitoring and putting effort and best-practices into your reputation if you want to gain good standing with people.

So start small, expand in a stable and steady manner, and always keep a watchful eye out for abuse, misuses, good and bad feedback, or anything else that might affect your reputation.

It's not only possible, but very practical; you just need to give it time and effort.